# NSInvalidArgumentException in SpriteKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skemitternode

I have an app with a SpriteKit scene. But if I run it on iOS 10.0  I'll get some error:

```
2018-11-09 21:58:26.379 App[56426:2425030] -[SKEmitterNode scaleMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c27adf0
2018-11-09 21:58:26.387 App[56426:2425030] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SKEmitterNode scaleMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c27adf0'
```

[image: View's hierarchy]

If I change View's class to UIView nothing will change.

Here is my scene setup:

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "TandM") {
            scene.size = self.view.frame.size
            scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
            tandmScene.presentScene(scene)
        }
```

But it's not trigger.

Full [log.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RJMA8rziNBXaWih76qW-ed79-DlYYQ_HiT1YtHSRp1o)

Comment: Is the error happening in the code you posted or elsewhere? `scaleMode` is a property of `SKScene` but the error shows that you are attempting to call it on an instance of `SKEmitterNode`.

Comment: @rmaddy It trigger in AppDelegate `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`
I have `SKEmitterNode.scaleMode` nowhere :(

Comment: You messed up something, just recreate the scene.

Comment: Oh brother, I am getting exactly this problem, these days ... suck ..

Answer (score 2):

"Do not create SKViews in Interface Builder in your storyboard, even if they are embedded in a UIView."
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1889/_index.html

Try to insert your SKView into view hierarchy in viewDidLoad method instead of adding it in storyboard. It should help.

I suggest, that this bug is fixed for iOS 11 and later, but it's unfortunately actual for iOS 10.